# Display tabular and editable data with koGrid or any other control

Tags: knockout.js, html-table

These are my requirements:

- I want to show tabular and editable data.
- Some columns are readonly and some are editable.
- The tabular "control" should allow me to define or create a template for a certain column to embed for example a html editor
- I do not need to sort/filter/group etc. this tabular "control"
- I want to bind this tabular "control" with KnockoutJS
- I am also using JQuery

What tabular control/widget fits my needs at best?

Do I have to use knockout grid or is a simple table enough or any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand you right, you don't need a grid control for your requirements in my opinion.

see this example made only with build in knockout features and some html (with bootstrap cause i'm lazy):

http://jsfiddle.net/infantrash/EPbEb/

you can easily make templates for your columns. very simple example: column "freetext" is editable, so if we are in edit mode, display an input field, otherwise just text.

```
<script type="text/html" id="freetext-template">
    <span data-bind="text: freetext, visible: $root.edit() == false"></span>
    <input data-bind="value: freetext, visible: $root.edit" />
</script>
```

i don't really see any need to use koGrid or any other control for such a simple scenario. you might wanna use it when it comes to sorting, filtering, paging...

Comment: Thanks, just what I have thought but I wasn`t sure about that :)